# Copy XML nodes to another XML includes child nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to create another xml whenever there is numerics in the zipname and move those related nodes to another xml 
Actual XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<IMAGE date="20200603" Time="141511">
-<ZipFile name="something.zip" Date="06032020" Time="131511">
<name="015522000970" line="001" status="STORED" />
<name="015522000990" line="002" status="STORED" />
</ZipFile>
-<ZipFile name="something111.zip" Date="06032020" Time="131511">
<name="015522000970" line="001" status="STORED" />
<name="015522000990" line="002" status="STORED" />
</ZipFile>
</IMAGE>

Result xml (Newone need tobe created):
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<IMAGE date="20200603" Time="141511">
-<ZipFile name="something111.zip" Date="06032020" Time="131511">
<name="015522000970" line="001" status="STORED" />
<name="015522000990" line="002" status="STORED" />
</ZipFile>
</IMAGE>
```

here is my code but it is not working . could anyone provide the approach how to copy

```
 XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName(XML_ZIPFILETAG);
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodeList)
            {
                XmlDocument xmkdoc1 = new XmlDocument();
                XmlNode copiedNode = xmlDoc.ImportNode(node,true);
                //SelectSingleNode(@"/Image/ZipFileName");
                //    node.InnerXml;
                XmlNode root = xmkdoc1.DocumentElement;
                xmkdoc1.CreateElement("DocumentElemnet");
                xmkdoc1.AppendChild(copiedNode);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close. When constructing the new document you need to build up the structure correctly. Try this (I did not test the code):

```
XmlDocument xmkdoc1 = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode root = xmkdoc1.createElement(XML_ZIPFILETAG);
xmkdoc1.AppendChild(root);
XmlNode copiedNode = xmlDoc.ImportNode(node,true);
root.AppendChild(copiedNode);
```